# Date Creation using PHP to suit HTML-input type date

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime, mktime

I am storing date in `coupon` table of `mysql` which is of `datetime` type. My dates are stored in `mysql` table as :-

```
2013-11-04 00:00:00
```

And while `editing` via HTML form. I am fetching value and putting value in HTML form as below :-

```
<input id="unlisted" type="date" name="coupon" class="input-large" 
value="<?php echo gmdate('Y-m-d' ,strtotime($edit['coupon'])); ?>" />
```

where `$edit['coupon'] = 2013-11-04 00:00:00`

- Problem is , It shows date 1 day back in form and after saving without doing any changes in date. date is getting saved 1 day back. `2013-11-03 00:00:00`.

Every time 1 click on edit and save without doing any changes in date. It goes 1 day back:- `2013-11-02 00:00:00` -> `2013-11-01 00:00:00` -> so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the problem is caused because of different **timezones**. The default timezone of you PHP installation is different from your actual location. To fix this you can simply set either default timezone or set it on specific function call.

You can set the default timezone of your PHP installation by editing `php.ini`. You can also change the default timezone programmatically:

```php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm');
```

to set timezone on specific call:

```php
strtotime($date_str . ' ' . $timezone);
```

You can also check your default timezone:

```php
date_default_timezone_get();
```

As you see 'Europe/Stockholm' is the string that represent the timezone. For the complete list of timezone you can refer to [List of supported timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) on PHP manual.

(If you use PHP > 5.2 you can use DateTime instead of strtotime.)

Happy coding :-)

Comment: Nope. It's not a timezone issue. I think probably problem is time. In Database Time is set as `00:00:00` which probably `strtotime` takes it as 1 day back.

Comment: strtotime doesn't take it as 1 day back, if it does PHP would be the most stupid language of all times. check for yourself `echo date('Y-m-d' , strtotime('2013-11-02 00:00:00'));`.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question, and explain more, add more details.